# numerically obtain "normalized" solutions for high order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, monte-carlo, numerical-calculus

As we know, for high order linear ODEs with non-constant coefficients we can hardly find an analytical solution, even if we can, the solution might involve very complicated special functions. An alternative way is to seek for numerical solutions.

However, here what I want is a solution $f(x)$ that is "normalized" and non-negative, i.e. 
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1
\end{equation}
and $f(x)\geq 0$.

If we try to get a numerical solution using Eular method, we can only specify the boundary conditions instead of forcing the solution to be "normalized" and non-negative.

Here are my questions:

1 How to determine if a non-negative non-zero integrable solution to a given ODE exists?

2 If we know such solution exists, is there any tracktable numerical methods to find a non-negative normalized solution? For example, something based on markov-chain monte-carlo?(I don't know, it's just a guess)

Here is the specific equation that I want to deal with:
\begin{equation}
a_4 f^{(4)}(x) + a_3 f^{(3)}(x) + a_2 f''(x) + (a_1 + b_1 x^2)f'(x) + (a_0 + b_0 x)f(x) = 0
\end{equation}
where $a_0, b_0, a_1, b_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ are constants.

Comment: Why do you suppose such a normalized and non-negative solution even exists? For example, the only integrable solution to $f'' = 0$ is the zero solution. Similarly for $f^{(4)}(x) = 0$.

Comment: We can force a function to be periodic by using a basis of periodic functions (Fourier series). Perhaps we can force a function to be normalized by using a basis of normalized functions, such as $$\frac{1}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\bigg(-\frac12\Big(\frac{x-b}{a}\Big)^2\bigg).$$ Then we would require not linear combinations, but convex combinations. (coefficients are non-negative and sum to $1$)

Comment: On a formal level: you can take the Fourier transform of your linear differential equation, due to the presence of the $x^2$ and $x$ factors your equation becomes a second order ordinary differential equation in $\xi$ with a regular singular point at the origin, which you can then approach using [Frobenius's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method). The positivity condition is hard to enforce, but the normalization becomes the requirement that the Fourier transform satisfied $\hat{f}(0) = 1$. After that you have to check the asymptotic properties of the solutions $\hat{f}$...

Comment: ... and if they decay sufficiently fast you can reasonably reconstruct the original $f$ using the inverse Fourier transform, at least numerically.

Comment: @mr_e_man I want $\int f =1$ instead of $\int f^2 = 1$, because the problem actually arises from a probability setting;  the basis functions you provided are not orthogonal and I am having difficulty dealing with it. Is there any basis which is normalized and orthogonal?

Comment: @WillieWong Sounds interesting. The equation usually have more than one solutions, even after normalization, so when solving the second order ODE obtained by fourier transform, which one should I choose?